# Dropdown selection to show total from tables in database

Tags: php, sqlsrv

[Form SHOWN HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlRtU.jpg)

The concept of what I am trying to do is with this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlRtU.jpg  I am wanting the object code to be selected and then the current code balance show the current balance from the database table.

In the Transaction table it will have the amount expense and the object code.  I want to add all of the amounts that have Object code "" whatever is selected on front form to pull from.
This is the transaction table. [Transaction Table Image][https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N6Sn.jpg]
If I can get it with the object code and the selected year that would be great but just getting the object code is perfect.  I need to find out how much is left in the budget when transactions are being entered.

Most of the code from the entry form is in php and the transactions table is in php along with connecting to SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

`SELECT SUM(amount) FROM [Transaction] WHERE code = 'Tools - 5508'`

Comment: but if I dont know what code they are going to choose.  I actually made a table that has the code_name, budget_year, start_balance and  current_balance.  
I just need to now add all the transactions up within a certain year and object code and display in box once the code is selected.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah Tools - 5508 was an example... You need to capture the input from the dropdown and then out in in a prepared statement like `SELECT SUM(amount) FROM [Transaction] WHERE code = ? AND year = ?`

Comment: Use backticks at either side of your code or edit your question with a codeblock

Comment: My thing is though if I put that in the actually page of code now do I format it so when the code is selected how does it know what to pull.  I made another page that shows the beginning balance, current balance with code and year.  I need the sum of all of the debits from one table added together and subtracted from the beginning balance for the selected year and displayed in that current code balance text box.